# How to add 2 rule to a jQuery if statement

Tags: jquery

I am not the best at jQuery. hoping someone can help with a small issue I am having. I have a password validation script and is trying to add 2 rules to a if statement but it is no working. below is my code.

```
function validatePassword() {
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#conf_password").val();

if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#validate_pass ").empty().append("Passwords do not match!").removeClass("alert-    
success").addClass("alert-error");
else
    $("#validate_pass").empty().append("Passwords match.").addClass("alert-success");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#conf_password").keyup(validatePassword);
});
```

This works great. I am trying to hide the submit button in the form using  $(".btn-save").hide(); . if I place this after here it breaks the function.

```
    if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#validate_pass ").empty().append("Passwords do not match!").removeClass("alert-    
    success").addClass("alert-error");
 $(".btn-save").hide();
  else
```

Comment: what do you mean by it breaks the function

Comment: does not execute at all. usually if i type an invalid password it will append the message but after i add hide condition it does not work

Comment: you are probably getting a syntax error, because the `else` is not connected to the `if` anymore. You need to put brackets `{}` around the if block: `if(password != confirmPassword){...}else{...}`

Comment: Firstly, dont validate password in frontend. Secondly, use $.trim() so strip whitespaces. Thirdly, put some brackets in your ifs. {}.

Comment: Thanks Rhumborl. your suggestion works!

Comment: @doniyor He is only "validating" *same* password here.

Comment: hi doniyor. i have php to do validation already but wanted to add just a jquery validation for front end.

Comment: @anand26 oh ok, then it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if the below code solves your problem. Please let me know the result as I didn't test the below code. I guess you are missing {} in your if syntax. Thanks

```
if (password !== confirmPassword)
{
    $("#validate_pass ").empty().append("Passwords do not match!").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-error");
    $(".btn-save").hide();
}
else
{
    $("#validate_pass").empty().append("Passwords match.").addClass("alert-success");
}
```